# Scope of fortran modules

Tags: scope, fortran

I already asked this question however this im going to try to be clearer this time. 
Im really new to fortran so forgive any sytax error this is more psuedo code.

```
module variables
   implicit none
   SAVE

   integer x
   integer y

 end module

subroutine init()

  use variables

  x = x + 2
  y = y + 1
endsubroutine
```

then my main program would be

```
 program main
    use variables
    implicit none

    call init()

    call some_other_function()
  endprogram
```

If i included my modules will they retain their values in some_other_function()
assume that some_other_function() is an abstraction of a huge simulation program. 
Can i rely on my initialized variables staying keeping their values.

is that was the SAVE statement in the module does?

Background info: I have program1 that is being called by program2
for a a significant amount of time. Program1 has a huge intilization phase that only needs to happen once. If I ran that initial phase before program2 calls program1, could i rely on all the module declared variables being saved

Comment: Also i there a difference between doing a endsubroutine save, 
or include the save in the module

Answer (score 3):

With a `SAVE` statement in the module, the values of the module variables are retained for the duration of the run of the program. If you initialize them in one procedure, the main program and other procedures will see those value. Module variables are preserved as long as they are in scope, so since you `use` your example module from the main program, their values would be retained for the duration of the run even without the `SAVE` statement.   In principle, if a module was only used in some procedures and a `SAVE` statement were not used, the compiler could "forget" the values when none of the procedures were in the call chain.  Probably many or perhaps all compilers don't actually reset the values ... it would be extra work to figure out whether a module had gone out of scope.

P.S. Your example has an error since you never initialize x and y.  You only change their values.

Comment: +1: As a minor note, F2008 specifies that module variables are implicitly SAVE'd.

Comment: Now another problem is that the software im dealing with. Has one simulation program1 calling another simulation program2.

Program2 has the potential to run on multiple threads. Im pretty sure this present a problem since program2 is written using mainly includes of SAVE modules, so variables can be overwritten while they are still needed. 

Is there an easy fix for this. Could I make a derived type, that is simply an include of all these modules.

Comment: @RobertLemiesz: Yes, that sounds like a problem. And no, there is no easy fix. Retrofitting thread safety into a program designed without that in mind tends to be a lot of work..